# i want to use Regex.IsMatch to find TB, GB, MB in VB.net Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a textbox which i need to validate for the below entries and also need to replace

**"3 GB"** valid input

**"3.2 GB"** valid input

**"3.2GB"** valid input >> then replace as **"3.2 GB"**

**"3.2"** invalid input, ask for follow correct format `MsgBox("follow the format like: 1 TB or 1.1 TB, 1 GB, 10 MB")`

**"VGGGB"** invalid input, ask for follow correct format `MsgBox("follow the format like: 1 TB or 1.1 TB, 1 GB, 10 MB")`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()
    Dim nInput, value
    Dim ChkDecimal As Double
    If input IsNot "" Then
        If input.EndsWith("TB") Then
            nInput = input.Replace("TB", "")
            If nInput IsNot vbNullString And IsNumeric(nInput) Then
                value = Convert.ToDouble(nInput)
                value = CDbl(value * 1048576 + 1)
                ChkDecimal = FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1048576), 2) Mod 1 ' check the number has a valid Decimal value
                If ChkDecimal = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1048576), 0) & " TB")
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1048576), 2) & " TB")
                End If
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid format!! should like: 99.99 MB/GB/TB")
            End If
        ElseIf (input.EndsWith("GB")) Then
            nInput = input.Replace("GB", "")
            If nInput IsNot vbNullString And IsNumeric(nInput) Then
                value = Convert.ToDouble(nInput)
                value = CDbl(value * 1024)
                ChkDecimal = FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1024), 2) Mod 1 ' check the number has a valid Decimal value
                If ChkDecimal = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1024), 0) & " GB")
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(CDbl(value / 1024), 2) & " GB")
                End If
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid format!! should like: 99.99 MB/GB/TB")
            End If
        ElseIf input.EndsWith("MB") = True Then
            nInput = input.Replace("MB", "")
            If nInput IsNot vbNullString And IsNumeric(nInput) Then
                value = Convert.ToDouble(nInput)
                value = CDbl(value * 1)
                Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(CDbl(value * 1), 0) & " MB")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid format!! should like: 99.99 MB/GB/TB")
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid format!! should like: 99.99 MB/GB/TB")
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Capacity input Format: 99.99 MB/GB/TB")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider a better UI that is more self-validating, like a `NumericUpDown` for the number and a `ComboBox` for the units. Using a GUI like a commandline is a bit primitive. Of course, that is unless you are required to do it the way you described because this is homework, in which case you're asking us to cheat for you. If you want to use `Regex` then show us that you've tried to do so. Do your research, make an attempt and then post here if what you think should work does not. That's how this site works.

Comment: sir, i have done at my own way.

Answer (score 0):

- I wouldn't use a regular-expression for this, because there's a much simpler (and more robust!) approach described below.
- If you do use a regular-expression, you'll need to add all of the unit names to the expression, which is painful. Regular-expressions are not well-suited to accepting a large list of *possible* literal inputs.
- Using a regular-expression would also mean the input would not be culture-aware, which is bad for usability (as many places around the world swap the `,` and `.` glyphs in numbers) - and you really don't want to handle things like digit-grouping, etc.

Instead, first extract and validate the unit name, then parse the numeric value using `Decimal.TryParse`

Like so (using C# because it's 2am here and I'm not getting paid to write this answer):

```
void Example()
{
    String textBoxValue = "3 GB";
    if( TryParseBinaryDataQuantity( textBoxValue, out Int64 valueBytes ) )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Visual Basic is dead." );
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Input is not a valid binary data quantity." );
    }
}

public static Boolean TryParseBinaryDataQuantity( String input, out Int64 valueBytes )
{
    input = ( input ?? "" ).Trim();
    if( input.Length < 3 ) // input is too short to be meaningful.
    {
        valueBytes = default;
        return false;
    }

    // Extract the unit-name by taking the last 3 characters of the input string and trimming any whitespace (this isn't the most robust or correct approach, but I'm feeling lazy):
    String unitName = input.Substring( startIndex: input.Length - 3 );

    // Validate the unit-name and get the bytes multiplier:
    if( !TryParseBinaryDataUnit( unitName, out Int64 multiplier ) )
    {
        valueBytes = default;
        return false;
    }

    // Consider repeating the above but for the last 2 characters of the string in order to match input like "3GB" instead of "3GiB" and "3 GB" and "3 GiB".

    // Parse and multiply:
    String numberPart = input.Substring( startIndex: 0, length: input.Length - 3 );
    if( Decimal.TryParse( numberPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out Decimal quantity )
    {
        Decimal bytesValue = quantity * multiplier;

        // Fail if the bytesValue is non-integral or negative:
        if( bytesValue != Math.Floor( bytesValue ) || bytesValue < 0 )
        {
            valueBytes = default;
            return false;
        }

        return (Int64)bytesValue;
    }
}

private static Boolean TryParseBinaryDataUnit( String unitName, out Int64 equivalentBytes )
{
    if( "GB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // or 1000 * 1000 * 1000 depending on if you're differentiating between GiB and GB.
        return true;
    }
    else if( "GiB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        return true;
    }
    else if( "MiB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024 * 1024;
        return true;
    }
    else if( "MB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024 * 1024;
        return true;
    }
    else if( "KB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024;
        return true;
    }
    else if( "KB".Equals( unitName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive ) )
    {
        equivalentBytes = 1024;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        equivalentBytes = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use proper library to parse the given input. I have used one in past for doing this (https://github.com/omar/ByteSize)

Here is quick example of how you can do this. I know there must be better way to do this but this would do the job =)

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
input = input.ToLower();
var reg = Regex.Match(input, "([\\d\\.]+)");
if (reg.Success && double.TryParse(reg.Groups[1].Value, out double rawSize))
{
    if (input.EndsWith("tb"))
        Console.WriteLine(ByteSize.FromTeraBytes(rawSize));
    else if (input.EndsWith("gb"))
        Console.WriteLine(ByteSize.FromGigaBytes(rawSize));
    else if (input.EndsWith("mb"))
        Console.WriteLine(ByteSize.FromMegaBytes(rawSize));
    else if (input.EndsWith("kb"))
        Console.WriteLine(ByteSize.FromKiloBytes(rawSize));
}
```

Input> 1234.56mb

Output> 1.23 GB

Comment: vb.net question

Answer (score 0):

You can try my method as following:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '1.3 GB
        '1.3gb
        '1gb
        Console.WriteLine("Pleasen input your entry:")
        Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim str1 As String = str.Substring(str.Length - 2, 2)
        If str1.ToUpper = "TB" Or str1.ToUpper = "GB" Or str1.ToUpper = "MB" Then
            Dim str2 As String = str.Remove(str.Length - 2)
            Dim str3 As String = str.Substring(str2.Length - 1, 1)
            If str3 = " " Then
                Dim str4 As String = str.Remove(str.Length - 3)

                If Regex.IsMatch(str4, "^\d*[.]?\d*$") Then
                    MsgBox("valid input")
                Else
                    MsgBox("follow the format like: 1 TB or 1.1 TB, 1 GB, 10 MB")
                    Return
                End If
            Else
                If Regex.IsMatch(str2, "^\d*[.]?\d*$") Then
                    TextBox1.Text = str.Insert(str.Length - 2, " ")
                    MsgBox("valid input")
                Else
                    MsgBox("follow the format like: 1 TB or 1.1 TB, 1 GB, 10 MB")
                    Return
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("follow the format like: 1 TB or 1.1 TB, 1 GB, 10 MB")
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```